# ¿Cómo configurar un contenedor de Docker con MySQL en un servidor y que este me deje acceder desde otro equipo para manipular las bases?

Tags: mysql, docker, dbeaver, contenedor

Buenas tardes antes que nada... **Tengo un contenedor de MySQL en Docker** en un **servidor** y quiero saber como se configura para que las bases de datos almacenadas en el(contenedor) puedan ser **manipuladas desde un equipo (Cliente)**. de modo que se pueda utilizar con **DBeaver como gestor de base de datos...**
gracias desde ya...

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el contenedor que yUtiliza el contenedor que ya existe de mysql, solo tiene que versión necesitas.
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql
Aquí esta un ejemplo
https://manticore-labs.com/2019/02/24/conexion-a-una-base-de-datos-mysql-utilizando-docker-y-dbeaver/

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).